# Character of action of permutations on a subset

Tags: modules, representation-theory

I have a problem involving characters of a certain $\mathbb C$$G$-module, where $G = S_n$. The module is the vector-space $V$ with basis $\{v(I) | I\subset\{1,...,n\}，|I| = k\}$, where $k\le n$. With $\chi$ the character induced by the natural action of $S_n$ on $V$, the question asks to prove,

$(\chi,\chi )=min(k,n-k)+1$

But I am struggling to find a way to tackle this. My attempts have involved direct calculation but I didn't find a nice way to characterise the sum. I have also tried to deduce through applying similar ideas to those that are use when dealing with the normal permutation character. This included that the inner product is related to fixed points, or even related to the orbits of $V\times V$. But in all cases I can't see any way to characterise the orbits or fixed points.

I believe this problem has some connections with quite deep representation theory, but I would like a more combinatorial approach to the problem, seeing as I have only had a basic introduction to representation and character theory!

Comment: Whenever $\chi$ is a permutation character coming from a finite group acting on a set $X$, the inner product $(\chi,\chi)$ calculates the number of orbits on the diagonal action of $G$ on the set $X\times X$. I think this helps for it looks like the orbits would consist of pairs $(I_1,I_2)\in V\times V$ such that the size of $I_1\cap I_2$ is fixed. Haven't checked everything. Probably it is better to look at the complements, when $k$ is large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality $k\leq n/2$ (otherwise replace $k$ by $n-k$, the modules are isomorphic via the complement map).  As Jyrki points out, it is enough to show that there are exactly $k+1$ orbits on $V\times V$. Certainly if $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ lie in the same orbit then $|a \cap b |=|c \cap d|$. This intersection can have any size between $0$ and $k$, because $k\leq n/2$. So there are at least $k+1$ orbits, and if we show all pairs $(a,b)$ with fixed $|a \cap b|$ lie in the same orbit then there are exactly $k+1$.

Suppose $|a \cap b| = r \leq k$. The subsets $a \cap b, a\setminus (a \cap b), b \setminus (a \cap b)$ are disjoint so we can choose a permutation $\pi \in S_n$ such that $\pi$ maps $a \cap b$ to $\{1,\ldots,r\}$, $a \setminus (a\cap b)$ to $\{r+1,\ldots,k\}$ and $b \setminus (a\cap b)$ to $\{ k+1,\ldots,k+(k-r)\}$. Then
$$ \pi (a,b) = (\{1,\ldots,k\}, \{1,\ldots,r\}\cup \{k+1\ldots,2k-r\})$$
and every such pair $(a,b)$ therefore lies in the orbit of $(\{1,\ldots,k\}, \{1,\ldots,r\}\cup \{k+1\ldots,2k-r\})$.

Comment: I was struggling with this for ages but didn't simplify it as smart as this. Cheers